# I keep getting a "Type Mismatch" error when I try to Loop through a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I want to delete an entire column if the header in cells `B5:P5` contains specific text.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Make_Prod()

Sheets("4. Partic Charges - Final").Select
Dim i As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim EndCell As Range
Dim MyValue As Range
Set StartCell = Range("B5")
Set EndCell = StartCell.End(xlToRight)

'Delete IID, LastName, FirstName, SSN, DOB, DOT, VestBal, TotalSourceDH, HasCovg, and any blank headers with values in column

For i = StartCell To EndCell
    MyValue = Range(i & 5)
        If MyValue = "IID" _
        Or MyValue = "LastName" _
        Or MyValue = "FirstName" _
        Or MyValue = "DOB" _
        Or MyValue = "DOT" _
        Or MyValue = "HasCovg" _
        Or MyValue = "" _
    Then Range(5 & i).EntireColumn.Delete

Next i
    
End Sub
```

Every time I try to run the code, I get a

> Type Mismatch

error on my `i = StartCell to EndCell` statement.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: They are ranges, so you'll need to use `for each` to itterate through these, `for each c in range(range("a1"),range("a10")):debug.? c.address:next c` for example.  Or you can use `startcell.row to endcell.row`

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you"  for the answer below, vote on or accept that person's answer by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%20To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A%20%201%20Choose,un-accept%20the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.%20More%20)

Answer (score 3):

The immediate cause of your error was as Nathan_Sav points out that you are trying to loop through a range using a number.

Try this. As you're deleting columns you need to iterate backwards to avoid skipping cells. Set the range (which you could do in one line) and then use a counter variable to loop through each cell.

You don't need `Select Case`, you can stick with `If` but in my view is a little clearer.

```
Sub Make_Prod()

Sheets("4. Partic Charges - Final").Select
Dim i As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim EndCell As Range
Dim MyValue As Range
Set StartCell = Range("B5")
Set EndCell = StartCell.End(xlToRight)

'Delete IID, LastName, FirstName, SSN, DOB, DOT, VestBal, TotalSourceDH, HasCovg, and any blank headers with values in column
Dim r As Range, c As Long

Set r = Range(StartCell, EndCell)

For c = r.Count To 1 Step -1
    Select Case r.Cells(c).Value
         Case "IID", "LastName", "FirstName", "SSN", "DOB", "DOT", "VestBal", "HasCovg", ""
            r.Cells(c).EntireColumn.Delete
    End Select
Next c

End Sub
```